# Telegram-бот не реагирует на команды. Python/Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я использую библиотеку telebot под python, для написания telegram бота. Я рефакторил управляющий скрипт и обнаружил, что бот перестал отзываться на команды. При попытке ввести '/start', 'start', воспользоваться любыми другими командами, которые поддерживает управляющий скрипт, ничего не происходит.

Интерпретатор не подсвечивал никаких ошибок, я уверен, что проблема может скрываться в функции get_message_bot или в декораторе @bot.message_handler(commands = ['start', 'refresh']). Что - то из них подхватило - бы введённую строку, но этого не происходит.

Это не проблема на стороне Telegram. Первая версия управляющего скрипта "отзывается" на команды и работает правильно. К сожалению, мне не удалось увидеть ошибку самостоятельно, я неопытен.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKEN = 'не хочу палить мой токен'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

#Получение текста, что вводит пользователь
#Раздел костылей: проверка на команду '/команда'
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def response(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda c:True)
def inln(inbutton):
    if inbutton.data == 'rescue':
        main(inbutton.message)
    if inbutton.data == 'sos':
        sos(inbutton.message)


#Главное меню
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['menu'])
def main(message):
  #Удалил код, чтобы не нагромождать пост

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, maintext, reply_markup = markup) #Бот скинет данные в чат, увы, тут нужен костыль

    if get_message_bot == 'продать':
        newlot(message)
    if get_message_bot == 'профайл':
        profile(message)
    


#Выводится при первом запуске бота '/start'
#Выводится при перезапуске бота '/refresh'
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start', 'refresh'])
def start(message):

    #ВНИМАНИЕ! Необходимо сделать проверку согласно БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ
    #Если пользователь зарегистрирован раннее, при команде /start даём полный доступ
    starttext = message.from_user.first_name + ", добро пожаловать на маркетплейс! Давай для начала настроим твой профиль - без него, ты не сможешь воспользоваться сервисом."
    starttext2 = message.from_user.first_name + ", ты в любой момент можешь посмотреть доступные команды. Набери /help Если у тебя внезапно пропали кнопки - эта команда точно поможет"
    starttext3 = "Эта опция сейчас недоступна. Авторизируйтесь."
    
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width = 1)
    
    entry_btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Создать профиль')
    entry_btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Получить помощь')
    entry_btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('У меня есть профиль')

    markup.add(entry_btn1, entry_btn2, entry_btn3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, starttext1, reply_markup = markup)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, starttext2, reply_markup = markup)

    if get_message_bot == "у меня есть профиль":
        main(message)
    if get_message_bot == "получить помощь" or get_message_bot == "/support":
        support(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, starttext3) #else может сработать некорректно

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['list'])
def helplist(message):
    helptext = '''/start - в главное меню
/support - поддержка
/sos - написать модератору
/arbitry - арбитраж
/profile - редактировать профиль
/lots - посмотреть лоты
/setlot - выставить лот
/promo - посмотреть акции'''

    helptext2 = 'У вас исчезли кнопки с экрана? Нажмите ниже, чтобы восстановить!'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, helptext)

    listkeyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Вернуть кнопки', callback_data = 'rescue'))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, helptext2, reply_markup = listkeyboard)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score 7):

Коллеги, я обращаюсь ко всем, кто зайдёт на эту страничку. У проблемы есть решение. На stackoverflow куча постов с этим же вопросом, но без ответа. Экспериментальным путём я решил свою проблему.

Если у вас в боте есть декоратор, который обрабатывает текст пользователя:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def response(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()
```

То он должен находиться в самом низу вашего кода (разумеется, до bot.polling()).
Любой код, который записан ниже этого декоратора (кроме bot.polling()) не будет выполнен.

Comment: Ты лучший, оно даж не гуглилось, пока я сам не начал задавать вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: Красава, спасибо. Рефакторил и bot.polling() вызываю до того как инициализировал все команды поту. Просто перед bot.polling() импортирую файл с декораторами бота и все начало запускаться.